# I hava problem about "template literals" when i use in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-literals

when I start vscode Template literals working,[Template literals working when i start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOrel.png). But "1s" after Template literals not working.[Template literals not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeoeZ.png)

I installed ESLint and I make sure ESLint works properly. Help me please T_T

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your template literals need to use back tick ``` `` ``` and not single quote `''`

```
`text ${variable}` // works
'text ${variable}' // will not work
```